# GridView/ListView Double Click

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, gridview

I am trying to get a listview/grid view that has clickable rows.
I am using MVVM'ish style design so my datacontext does point to another class.

i have tried the following with no successes

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding DelegateUsers}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
  <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="Auto">
                        <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Header1">
                            <GridViewColumnHeader.InputBindings>
                                <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding CommandDoubleClick}"/>
                            </GridViewColumnHeader.InputBindings>
                        </GridViewColumnHeader>
```

When i put the input bindings into the  i can get the command to trigger however it only triggers in white space not on any of the items in the listview.

has anyone got any good ideas on how to accomplish this please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using event triggers.

Include

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
```

And on your xaml file,

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding DelegateUsers}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
  <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
     <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CommandDoubleClick}"/>
  </i:EventTrigger>  
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
  <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="Auto">
                        <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Header1">

                        </GridViewColumnHeader>
```